# Dominant rational maps and dimension of affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

Say we have $f : X \dashrightarrow Y$ as a dominant rational map between two affine varieties. Is it necessarily true that $\dim Y \leq \dim X$?

$f$ being dominant means that we must have that $f(\text{dom}(f)) = Y$, however I don't quite see how this may give the desired inequality.